# Send user input from Ajax Stimulus controller to Ruby controller as variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, stimulusjs

In my Home controller, I basically have a variable inside of `def index`: `target = 13.5`. I use this to do a lot of calculations which I send to my index.html view. My aim is to allow the user to input a value that directly updates this variable. I am using the below Stimulus controller, but want it so that if someone types in '14', the variable becomes `target = 14`, which my controller then updates the calculation and is updated to the user in real time.

In ajax_controller.js:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="ajax"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['form', 'output']
  connect() {
    console.log(this.formTarget);
    console.log(this.outputTarget);
  }


  send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(this.formTarget.action, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
      body: new FormData(this.formTarget)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.outputTarget.innerHTML = data.body.number;
      });
  }
}
```

In index.html.erb:

```
<div class="input-form" data-controller="ajax">
  <%= form_with url: receive_path, data: { ajax_target: 'form', action: 'submit->ajax#send' } do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :number %>
    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
  <p data-ajax-target="output"></p>
</div>
```

In home_controller.rb:

```
def index
 target = 13.5

 #DO LOTS OF CALULATIONS HERE THAT EVENTUALLY OUTPUT TO A VIEW. I WOULD LIKE THE ABOVE TARGET UPDATED BY INPUT THAT THEN UPDATES THE CALCULATIONS 
end

def receive
  render json: { body: params }
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
  root 'home#index'
  post 'receive', to: 'home#receive'
```

Comment: have you checked what is submitted to the controller?
`puts params` to print it to the console or set a breakpoint with `binding.irb` to inspect it.

Comment: @Pascal I get this in console: _Processing by HomeController#receive as JSON
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "number"=>"3"}._ So am I right in thinking I can access the number in  HomeController#receive? How would I send it to my Home#index controller specifically? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the form is submitted to the `receive` action, then you can access the form fields using `params`.
Now you could extract the calculation that you have in `index` action into its own method and then call this methd from `receive`, püassing the params needed for the calculation along.